# can't initialize tomcat in Xampp

Tags: tomcat, xampp

I'm trying to use xampp for a course but i can't make tomcat work correctly, the error i get is:

"Tomcat Started/Stopped with errors, return code: 1
Make sure you have Java JDK or JRE installed and the required ports are free
Check the "/xampp/tomcat/logs" folder for more information"

I've seeing many others with this problem but none of the advices they get helped me get rid of it.

i've already settled the enviroment variables like this:

- CATALINA_HOME: C:\xampp\tomcat
- CLASSPATH: C:\xampp\tomcat\lib\servlet-api.jar;C\xampp\tomcat\lib\jsp-api.jar
- JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9
- JRE_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9
- path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9\bin;C:\xampp\Tomcat\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre-9\bin

I've already set the port to 7070 (not sure if this is valid)

when i run CATALINA_START from cmd i got this:

```
C:\xampp\tomcat>catalina_start

[XAMPP]: Searching JDK HOME with reg query ...
'reg' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
'reg' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

[XAMPP]: Seems fine!
[XAMPP]: Set JAVA_HOME : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9
[XAMPP]: Set CATALINA_HOME : C:\xampp\tomcat

Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\xampp\tomcat"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\xampp\tomcat"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\xampp\tomcat\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jre-9"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\xampp\tomcat\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\xampp\tomcat\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\xampp\tomcat\endorsed is not supported. Endorsed standards and standalone APIs
in modular form will be supported via the concept of upgradeable modules.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Apache and MySQL works just fine, but tomcat is giving headaches Does anyone know what can be wrong?

Comment: See my answer in [XAMPP tomcat service is not starting with error as “Tomcat Started/Stopped with errors, return code: 1”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54024290/2761103) for what went wrong and how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled 1.9 and installed 1.8 and Tomcat started up and worked immediately. Another option would be to install Tomcat 9 outside xampp and run it with java 1.9, but for my purposes running tomcat 7 with java 1.8 is sufficient.